# Simplifying rationals during assignment

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign the numerator and denominator values to a rational object, but need to reduce them to their smallest corresponding numbers. Say for example I input 10 for the numerator, and 20 for the denominator, I need them reduced down to 1/2. Below is my constructor that takes a numerator and denominator and assigns them to the objects member variables.

```
Rational::Rational(int num, int denom) {
    try {
        this->num = num / gcd(num, denom);
        this->denom = denom / gcd(num, denom);
    }
    catch(RationalException ex) {
        cout << "Cannot set denominator to 0" << endl;
    }
}
```

The gcd function is imported from an external .h file which is supposed to be used in the reduction process. But this code when run doesn't assign the reduced values into the member variables.

I've tried this alternative approach:

```
Rational::Rational(int num, int denom) {
    try {
        this->num = num;
        this->denom = denom;

        num /= gcd(this->getNumerator(), this->getDenominator());
        denom /= gcd(this->getNumerator(), this->getDenominator());
    }
    catch(RationalException ex) {
        cout << "Cannot set denominator to 0" << endl;
    }
}
```

and it also doesn't reduce the object, not sure how to approach this outside of creating an external function but I won't be able to manipulate the member variables as the function will be considered nonmember.

Below is the code for the gcd function

```
#ifndef GCD_H
#define GCD_H

inline int gcd(int a, int b) {return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);}

#endif
```

Edit: Added gcd code

Comment: Q: "But this code when run doesn't assign the reduced values into the member variables"???  Please clarify...

Comment: It doesn't do the reduction and assign the reduced value. When I run the code and I pass 10 and 20, it will assign them as is, they won't get turned into 1 and 2.

Comment: The version with `this->num =` assigns the result to the member variables. The version with `num /=` does not

Comment: How is `gcd` declared?

Comment: @NateEldredge I added the code for gcd

Comment: The first version seems to work okay: https://godbolt.org/z/oMox64jr6.  The bug in the second version has already been pointed out.

Comment: Please show a (minimal) `main` function that demonstrates "when run doesn't assign the reduced values into the member variables". I am thinking of something like `int main() { Rational value(10, 20); std::cout << value.numerator() << '/' << value.denominator(); /* or however you view these values */ }` -- it should be just complete enough so that someone can copy, compile, and run your code to reproduce your result.

Comment: [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

1. Save the return value of "gcd()" into a temp variable
2. Step through the debugger to ensure each of the three variables are updated correctly:

   ```
   Rational::Rational(int num, int denom) {
       try {
           int g = gcd(num, denom);  // <-- Set bkpt here, step through in debugger
           this->num = num / g;
           this->denom = denom / g;
       }
       catch(RationalException ex) {
           cout << "Cannot set denominator to 0" << endl;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: And another suggestion: don't shadow member variables with arguments. It just creates confussion.

Comment: Another suggestion; just use [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) rather than rolling your own.